# Intersection of Plane Curve and Line

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Question: Suppose $C$ is an affine plane curve and L is a line in $A^2(K)$, $L\not\subset C$. Suppose $C=V(F)$ and $F\in K[x,y]$ a polynomial of degree n. Show that $L\cap C$  is a finite set of no more than n points.

My attemp:
Btw, I saw this question nearby similar question but I can't understand writings about the proof.

First, I don't know meaning of affine plane curve. Now, $F$ is polynomial so $V(F)$ is zero set of polynomial and $L$ is a line in $A^2$ so it is something like $y=ax+b$. If a point $(a,b)$ in $L \cap C$ then it satisfies the following $F(a,b)=0$ and we have this line $ y=ax+b$.

I am stuck with it now.

Thanks in advance

Comment: An affine plane has the form $a_0^{\intercal} \, x + b_0 = 0$ and a line is a $n-1$ dimensional plane also with form $$a_1^{\intercal} \, x + b_1 = 0$$. I do not understand the notation $A^2$, $V(F)$ and $F \in K[x, y]$. Are there additional information?

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AffineFunction.html

Comment: Hint: Consider $F(x, ax+b)$. This is a polynomial in one variable of degree at most $n$. Also, note that a vertical line $x = c$ can't be written in the form you've given, so some further argument is needed.

Comment: $V(F)$ is vanishing set , F is polynomial in $K[x,y]$ and $A^2 = \{ (a,b) : a,b \in K \}$ and $K$ is field.

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto these are well-known terms from an area of math called *algebraic geometry*. What you're doing right now is sort of the equivalent of wandering in to a calculus question for the first time and asking what $\int$ means - sure, it would be good for you to get an answer for that, but this isn't really the right place for those questions.

Comment: Let me make it verbose, without all these symbols: we have a 2 dimensional plane defined in space, a line and a surface given by monomials. All these scenario is within a $x \times y$ set K. You want to know if the intersection of L and C has no more than n points? And what is the role of the polynomial in this scene?